# How can 'a' view the stream while 'b' is recording it with RecordRTC

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, live-streaming, recordrtc

Using [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) how can I have one or more clients view the stream while it is being recorded. So for example, when user 'a' is recording their camera, how can 'b' view it. A meaningful answer will include a working example.

Almost as good would be a working example with something else than RecordRTC, as long as its focused on html/javascript.

Comment: "A meaningful answer will include a working example." Stackoverflow is not a place to have somebody write code for you. That is rent-a-coder. Stackoverflow can help you when you are writing code and are need help.

Comment: A working minimal example and production code are completely different things. Countless highly rated question/answer pairs involve working examples. In fact, it seems almost a best practice. For the kind of question I'm asking, an example is a basic requirement for the answer to be meaningful. This is completely consistent with the practice of stackoverflow.

Comment: So ok, I can see now that you are actually knowable in this matter, yet decided to contribute nothing of value at all. Is Stackoverflow overflow a place for that?

Comment: The problem is not that there should not be an example in the answer, the problem is you did not put enough effort into the question to warent such an answer. Your question is not a “I am having trouble with something, and I have exhausted all other avenues” question, it is “I need something, so somebody do it for me” question. What you are looking for is a free consultant. give it a try yourself, when you run into problems, update the post with what you tried, and what you are stuck with. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As i think you can use Broadcast Process. Means you can broadcast a's camera and also record that running stream with RecordRTC and other one can see that camera stream.
You can also make your stream private for a particular user.